# how to make a custom concurrent-list like that?

Tags: java, concurrency

HI，I write a function for counting PV, when come a PV, write the PV to redis. But I think the huge PV amounts may cause redis traffic problem. Then I use an ArrayList to cache the PV, and when the list size went up to 10, put all the 10 PV to redis, then clear the List.

Because the concurrent problem(List add, size, clear), I add synchronized to the funciton, the code just like this:

```
static ArrayList<Object> pvList = new ArrayList<Object>();
public synchronized void countPv(...){
    //........make a PV Object
    pvList.add(PV)
    if(pvList.size()>10){
        // add the 10 PV to redis
        addRedis(pvList.subList(0,10))
    }
    //delete
    pvList.subList(0,10).clear();
}
```

But in the stress test, it lost some PV, maybe the synchronized cause thread traffic problem, how to imporve this solutions?

1. put synchronized inside the function can improve a little.
2. ConcurrnetLinkedQueue, Concurrent...Array is not suit for this problem, I think
   thx

Comment: `ConcurrnetLinkedQueue, Concurrent...Array is not suit for this problem, I think thx` why you think so? And, your method is `synchronized` then where is your concurrent problem?

Comment: the concurrent problem is the array's add(), clear(). if one thread add and other thread clear(delete), or one thread add and other thread add will also cause concurrent problem. You can take a look at  the source code of ArrayList

Comment: when multi concurrent ConcurrnetLinkedQueue, e.g. 2 thread enter list.size >=10, then they will both add object to redis or clear the list. you can try to practice some code

Comment: Losing some PV may be caused by situation where in pvList is less than 10 elements at the end of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList `pvList` is a static member of the class, but your `countPv` method is non-static.

So your `synchronized` has no effect if you call the `countPv` method is called from different instance variables. Imagine this code is defined in a class `PVObjectListFiller`. So you have a thread 1 with this code:

```
PVObjectListFiller f1 = new PVObjectListFiller(...);
f1.countPv(...);
```

and the other thread:

```
PVObjectListFiller f2 = new PVObjectListFiller(...);
f2.countPv(...);
```

In this case these thread will not synchronize, because they are synchronized against different mutexes (the objects `f1` or `f2`).

To get synchronization into your method, you have different possibilities

Make the `countPv(...)` method static:

```
public static synchronized void countPv(...) {
    // ...
}
```

Other possibility: make the `pvList` member non-static:

```
ArrayList<Object> pvList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Third possibility: introduce a static `mutex` object for synchronization:

```
static ArrayList<Object> pvList = new ArrayList<Object>();
private static Object pvMutex = new Object();
public void countPv(...) {
    // ............... make PV Object
    synchronized(pvMutex) {
        pvList.add(PV)
        if(pvList.size()>10){
            // add the 10 PV to redis
            addRedis(pvList.subList(0,10))
        }
        //delete
        pvList.subList(0,10).clear();
    }
}
```

It depends on your requirements which solution should be preferred.

Comment: It's strange that no exception in my old code. If synchronized has no effect in my no-static method, the add and clear to List should throw exceptions. And some one suggest use method as CAS, the unsafe method in Java, So maybe can write someth like this
`
  ConcurrentLinkedQueue list = new ....
`